# Neutralizing/ removing the mothball/naphthalene smell from textbooks

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I was recently given some excellent (and very expensive) academic textbooks. Unfortunately they must have been immersed in mothballs for a long time. When I take them out of the box, the smell of naphthalene actually gives me a headache within minutes. I have tried airing them, covering them in sodium bicarbonate, but nothing has worked. Any ideas please?

Comment: Slowly in, slowly out. It is diffusion driven. Long term heating could work, but also may shorten the book life. Or storing next to well spread active carbon, which would be visual danger for the books.

Comment: If the weather is good and sunny, keep the opened books outside during daytime. Repeat until the smell goes away. This may take 1-2 weeks. Baking soda won't do anything.

Comment: Check out [these solutions](http://bookrepairsupply.com/featured/book-deodorizing/) from Book Repair Supply (not affiliated in any way).